# RelativeLayout alignment does not work

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to show the info about football matches. I would like something like this image:
[image]

In every line, I would like to have, in this order

- home team logo
- home team name
- match time
- guest team name
- guest team logo

I am using the following xml code for the single line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:padding="4dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:text="18:00"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/homeTeamLogo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/awayTeamLogo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/homeTeam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/homeTeamLogo"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/homeTeamLogo"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/time"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:text="home team" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/awayTeam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/time"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/awayTeamLogo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/awayTeamLogo"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:text="away team" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

in the preview of Android Studio I see the correct behavior:
[image]

but the result in the emulator and also in the real device is wrong:
[image]

I don't understand the reason, can someone help me, please?

In my viewHolder I set all data in the bind method, I use glide for images:

```
   public void bind(RequestManager glide, final Match match) {
    mTimeTV.setText(DateHelper.getMatchTime(match.getDate()));
    glide.load(match.getHomeTeamLogoPath())
            .into(mHomeTeamLogoIV);
    glide.load(match.getAwayTeamLogoPath())
            .into(mAwayTeamLogoIV);

    mHomeTeamTV.setText(match.getHomeTeamName());
    mAwayTeamTV.setText(match.getAwayTeamName());


}
```

AS requested I tried to put color as background, this is the preview:
[image]
and this is the result:
[image]

Comment: Are you sending home name correctly to the adater

Comment: yes data are correctly set

Comment: try putting backgrounds in different colors with transparency to each `View` in your layout (e.g. `android:background="#AAff0000"`), so you could see where each view is being located

Comment: Can you share adapter code?

Comment: I shared adaper code and also I tried to put colors in the textviews and maybe now the problem is more clear. I think the problem is about the to_right and to_left rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your xml with [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="4dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/homeTeamLogo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/homeTeam"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:text="home team"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/time"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/homeTeamLogo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="18:00"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/awayTeam"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:text="away team"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/awayTeamLogo"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/time"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/awayTeamLogo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Yes!! It works! thanks a lot! Do you know some good resource where I can learn about Constraint Layout?